# Interface method that takes any property class/model C#

Tags: c#

So, I want to create an interface which has a method that can take in any model class. For example

I have these three property class

```
class A
{
    public long id { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    public long someID { get; set; }
}

class C
{
    public long anydesign { get; set; }
}

class D
{
    public long Router { get; set; }
}
```

I have an interface

```
public interface IModel
{
    void Dosomething(A model); // Now in this example it takes the A model,But I want it to be set, so that that class that implements the interface can put any model as required
}
```

Now, I have a class that implements the mode Since the interface only takes the A model, I can pass in the A model in the class during implementation

```
public class ImplemenationA: IModel
{
    public void Dosomething(A model)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(model.description);
    }
}
```

Say i have another implemenation Class Now, I am guessing the below one wouldnt work, as the interface signature enforces only to take a Model A and not any other model

```
public class ImplementationB:IModel
{
   public void Dosomething(B model)
   {
        Console.WriteLine(model.someID);
   }
}
```

I want to the interface method to be invoked by any implementation class and use any model

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are looking for [Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/)

Comment: More specifically you're looking for [Generic Interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-interfaces)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on your description you may want to use Generics. Since you're creating separate implementations you can apply the interface below to achieve a similar result.

```
public interface IModel<T>
{
   void Dosomething(T model);
}
```

---

```
public class ImplementationB : IModel<B>
{
   public void Dosomething(B model)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(model.someID);
    }
}
```

Comment: would this still work , if the interface had a method that does not have anything to do with the model For example
public interface IModel<T>
{
   void Dosomething(T model); 
  void Donothing(string nothing);
}

Comment: Yes it would.  You would include a method definition in the IModel<T> interface for the void DoNothing(string nothing).  This would, however, require you to implement that method in all classes that implement IModel<T>

Answer (score 0):

Some sort of `Decorator` pattern can solve it, postpone your actual implementation to inner classes and insist on separation of concern, please leave a comment if I miss understood your question:

```
//added to support inner implementation 
interface IModelImpl {
 void Do();
}

class A: IModelImpl
{
    public long id { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }

    public void Do(){
        console.WriteLine(this.description);
    }
}

class B: IModelImpl
{
    public long someID { get; set; }
    public void Do(){
        console.WriteLine(this.someID);
    }
}

class C: IModelImpl
{
    public long anydesign { get; set; }
    public void Do(){
        ...
    }
}
```

Here is your IModel, pretty much the same, considered like an outer implementation:

```
public interface IModel
{
    void Dosomething(IModelImpl model); //put any model as long it implements IModelImpl 
}
```

Your class implementation should now changed to:

```
public class ImplemenationA: IModel
{
    public void Dosomething(IModelImpl model)
    {
       //Do more specific work to ImplementationA 
       model.Do();
    }
}
```

Another class implementation:

```
public class ImplementationB:IModel
{
   public void Dosomething(IModelImpl model)
   {
       //Do more specific work to ImplementationB like validation
       model.Do();
   }
}
```